# Can Sri Vaishnava Brahmanas offer meat to Vishnu and eat it as Prasadam?

Tags: vishnu, sri-vaishnava, food, prasad

Can Sri Vaishnava Brahmanas offer meat to Vishnu and eat it as Prasadam?

Is it possible for Sri Vaishnava Brahmanas to eat meat?

Comment: All Vaishnava temples that I know of, are very particular about vegetarianism.

Comment: Vishnu as deity is a sattvik God.How can be meat offered to Him by any sect?

Comment: In Vedic sacrifices Vishnu is offered meat... also does ur comment mean that animals (like goat etc), which don't eat meat, are sattvik? @Partha they are not actually

Comment: @Rickross No sattvik puja of even Devies allows animal sacrifice as per Tantra:)

Comment: All devas are sattvik only the people who worship defer

Comment: Meeting eating is forbidden for brahmanas so do devthathas

Comment: All the is sacrifice happened pre Buddha and Madhva